# Can VS Code TestItem double click actions be handled by an extension?

Tags: vscode-extensions

I have built a test explorer extension for VS Code and in the case where the test corresponds to a static file, I can assign a Uri and Range to the test node which results in the file being opened when the node is double clicked, which is great.  In other cases the test file is not static and needs to be generated programmatically from the tree context.

Is it possible to intercept the double click call to "do some work"?

Answer (score 0):

There is no official support for double clicking an [TreeItem](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#TreeItem), but I have managed to make a workaround by binding commands to the item. Note you cannot make it work with the `TreeView.onDidChangeSelection`, as it does not run on selecting(clicking) on an already selected item.

I'll try to keep the codes short, assuming you already know how to make a TreeView.

The outline:

1. Prepare an `onClick` command (or any name you want):

   1. add an entry to `contributes.commands` in `package.json`
   2. call `vscode.commands.regsiterCommand` with a proper commandId.
2. When creating your `TreeDataProvider` class, assign the command property when you implement the `getChildren()` method. TreeItem accepts a `command` property:

   > The Command that should be executed when the tree item is selected.

   Unlike `TreeView.onDidChangeSelection`, the command is fired even when it is already selected.
3. Since the command is fired on every click, we do a workaround of checking whether it is a *double* click. Save the tree item, along with the last time it was selected, and compare it on every selection. If it is the same item, and has been selected in less than, say 300~500ms, consider it as a double click, and do your work. If it is a different item, reset your last check. (See code sample below)

Here are the snippets for above outline:

`package.json`: declare command

```js
{
  // ...
  "contributes": {
    "commands": [
      { "command": "my-extension.onClick", "title": "On select item" }
    ]
  }
  // ...
}
```

`MyExtensionTreeDataProvider.ts`: declare command to fire on selection

```js
export class MyExtensionTreeDataProvider extends TreeDataProvider {
  // ...
  getChildren(treeItem) {
    const newItem = {
      label: 'double click me!',
    }
    // add a command property, and pass the item itself for identification
    newItem.command = {
      command: 'my-extension.onClick',
      arguments: [newItem],
    }
    return [newItem]
  }
  // ...
}
```

`extension.ts`: register/implement command

```js
// ...
export function activate(context) {
  // keep state
  let lastSelectedItem = null
  let lastSelectedAt   = Date.now()

  vscode.commands.registerCommand('my-extension.onClick', function handleClick(treeItem) {
    if (treeItem.collapsibleState !== vscode.TreeItemCollapsibleState.None) 
      return
    
    const now = Date.now()
    const isSameItem = treeItem === lastSelectedItem
    const isWithinShortTime = now - lastSelectedAt < 500
    if (isSameItem && isWithinShortTime) {
      vscode.window.showInformationMessage(`doubleclick! ${treeItem.label}`)
      // reset state
      lastSelectedItem = null
      lastSelectedAt   = now
    } else {
      // set new state
      lastSelectedItem = treeItem
      lastSelectedAt   = now
    }
  })
}
// ...
```

One caveat is that the command is also fired when you press Enter, so technically speaking what we've implemented here is a 'double select'.

Comment: Thanks for the excellent example here.  Unfortunately, the Test Explorer uses a [TestController](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#TestController) and  [TestItems](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#TestItem) which do not seem to have this same command attribute ... unless I am missing something.